# PyQt, change QTableWidgetItem background color in a range of cells

Tags: colors, background, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a `QTableWidget` populated with `QTableWidgetItems` and I would like to change the backgroud color for a range of cells (row n...m, all columns). Iterating over rows/colums and changing the bg color for each `QTableWidgetItem` by means of sth. like

```
for n in range(startRow, endRow):
  for c in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
    self.tableWidget.item(n,c).setBackgroundColor(self.tableBackgroundColor)
```

is painfully slow (about 4ms per item on an Intel i7, which is 4 sec. per 25*40 cells).

Is there a more performant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by switching to a Model/View approach. That is, use a `QTableView` and `QTableModel` instead of a `QTableWidget`. This approach is faster because the background color will only be calculated for the (hundred or so) visible cells instead for all thousand cells.

Using the Model/View approach requires some investment, but for larger tables it is certainly worth it.

The concepts are explained in [the Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html). There is also a [tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/modelview.html). They both have C++ code snippets <del>but it is not that hard to translate to PyQt</del> (actually, see my comment below).

Comment: On second thought, translating the C++ snippets may include some subtleties. I recommend to use the examples that come with the PyQt source. Download of the source distributions for [PyQt 4](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) or [PyQt 5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) and take a look at the itemviews examples, for instance `itemviews/spinboxdelegate.py`